# List all hotfixes applied to windows server

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows

There used to be a command line tool called QFECheck in Windows Server 2000 that would list them out.  Is this the preferred method on windows server 2003/2008?

I know they're listed in Add/Remove programs, but it's hard to capture them for an audit this way.

Can i do this without having to install an add-on executable?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The following command(s) work in both the 'regular' command prompt and PowerShell, *also* for both **Windows Server 2003** and **Windows Server 2008**:

```
wmic qfe get Hotfixid
```

to find if a specific update was installed:

```
wmic qfe | find "123456"
```

It however does not provide any office updates (unfortunately), thought it's relatively easy now to just go to 'installed updates' and do a search for it... same as Windows updates, but the question specified it needed to be done from a command prompt.

Powershell only command:

```
Get-Hotfix -id kb123456
```

Comment: +1 Can't believe I've never seen that tool....

Comment: I know the question is about Server but just to add - It seems to work on Win7 but on XP it returned a whole lot of unrelated garbage, such as about 50 repetitions of "File 1" and random text such as "NLSDownlevelMapping".

Comment: I just stumbled upon it by trying to figure out more about 'quick fix engineering', after finding this command online: 
    Get-WmiObject -query 'select * from win32_quickfixengineering' | foreach {$_.hotfixid}

Comment: Actually, I did notice the 'file 1' junk on win 2003... but the list of KBs was still accurate.

Comment: so awesome i changed you to the correct answer!

Comment: @Nick: Yeah, I don't blame you on that one :)

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with Powershell:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path “HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\HotFix”
```

Comment: I think your using powershell here to rub it in a bit, but that registry key is golden

Comment: Nah, not rubbing it in.  But, yeah, you admittedly could use any command-line reg tool.

Comment: this only works on 2003... I just posted a command that works for both server 2003 and 2008.

Answer (score 2):

PowerShell now includes the [Get-HotFix](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849836.aspx) command which is far easier to remember.

Answer (score -1):

they are also listed under the windows directory.